# Add the values from multiple columns, and compare it in the where clause

Tags: mysql

I made a SELECT to add different values from a row into a `maxguests` field.

What I do not manage is to re-use that virtual value in the WHERE clause.

My query is

```
SELECT 
    id,
    single_beds + single_bed_sofas + double_beds * 2 + double_bed_sofas * 2 AS maxguests
FROM items
```

and this works good, as expected.

Now I would like to add `WHERE maxguests > 5` but I get error that the colums is unknown.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'maxguests' in 'where clause'

Is aliasing that sum into `maxguests` not enough to be able to use it in the query?

Comment: You can only use aliased column names in group by, order by, and having clauses in MySQL.

Comment: @Gremash thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` clause to compare the virtual column value, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    single_beds + single_bed_sofas + double_beds * 2 + double_bed_sofas * 2 AS maxguests
FROM items
HAVING maxguests > 10;
```

Here is a example in **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f72/6/0)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try HAVING.

```
SELECT 
id,
single_beds + single_bed_sofas + double_beds * 2 + double_bed_sofas * 2 AS maxguests
FROM items
HAVING maxguests > 5
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 5 seconds :)

Comment: For this time only :),  @Gremash